# WCF configuration tool dont like behaviorExtensions?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, configuration

When trying to open my web.config with the Microsoft Service Configuration Editor I get exceptions about not finding extensions. The WCF application works fine with the extensions and if I remove them, then the Microsoft Service Configuration Editor will open the web.config without problem?

```
<extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="protobuf" type="ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.ProtoBehaviorExtension, protobuf-net, Version=2.0.0.580, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=257b51d87d2e4d67" />
        <add name="customBehaviorExtension_Integration" type="MyApp.ServiceImplementation.CustomRequestInterceptorBehaviorExtension_Integration, MyApp.ServiceImplementation" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
```

These extensions are used in 3 places later on.

I know that this problem have been around for a vary long time, but is ther yet no solution more then temporarly remove the extensions?